# File not found error when listing the directory but the file exists

Tags: linux, python-3.x, file-not-found

I wanted to list the whole directory in Linux using Python script but it doesn't work for some files and I don't know why.

This is the short script which lists the directory passed to the function:

```
import os

def main():
    files = os.listdir('/')
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        print(oct(os.stat(f).st_mode)[-3:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And I give you some the example of the problem. 
1) I want to print the name of the file which the script found.
2) I want to print the privileges to this file.

When I execute the script with the root directory as the argument of the function it produces FileNotFoundError:

```
shizzer@shizzer-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD ~ $ python3 /tmp/example.py
initrd.img
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/example.py", line 9, in main
    print(oct(os.stat(f).st_mode)[-3:])
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'initrd.img'
```

As you can see the file was found because its name is on the stdout - *initrd.img*.

In addition, I decided to show you the *ls -a* Linux command to prove that the *initrd.img* file really exists in the root directory:

```
shizzer@shizzer-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD / $ ls -a
    .    boot   etc         lib    libx32      mnt   root  srv  usr
    ..   cdrom  home        lib32  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
    bin  dev    initrd.img  lib64  media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
```

Could someone help me? I will be grateful!

Comment: In brief: `f` is the file name without the path. You must append the path to it before calling `stat`.

Comment: Yes, I duplicated the topic and I'm sorry about that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KamilSzpakowski Don't worry too much. It's not bad "per se" to have some duplicated question (if you did research first and haven't found it). Your question is clear, has a different title and also it contains a possible common error message that is not mentioned in the duplicate target question.